# Why does explorer restart automatically when I kill it with Process.Kill?

Tags: c#, .net-framework, process, windows-explorer, kill

If I kill explorer.exe like this:

```
private static void KillExplorer()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
    Console.Write("Killing Explorer... ");
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        process.Kill();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

It restarts immediately.

But if I use `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe`, or kill it from the task manager, it doesn't restart.

Why is that? What's the difference? How can I close explorer.exe from code without restarting it? Sure, I could call taskkill from my code, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution...

Comment: What Windows version are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570244/problem-with-killing-windows-explorer

Comment: Are you trying to write a kiosk app?

Comment: @t3hn00b, I tried it on XP and 7, with the same results.

Comment: @DanBarzilay, the accepted answer to this question doesn't work, and the others are not very helpful either. Please don't close.

Comment: @Jodrell, no, I'm trying to write a setup for an application; the application installs a shell extension, so I need to kill explorer before I can overwrite a previous installation.

Comment: Why was this post migrated? It has nothing to do on SuperUser...

Comment: Ironically, I was looking for a simple C# only solution to restart Explorer and the code in the question fits my requirements perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say that I haven't cheated to get the answer. All credits go to morguth for his post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/df5860a6-a44f-4ea8-aa8d-e812beaf9acb).

What he has suggested (and proved work on my Win7 and XPMode) is that there is a registry key that forces the shell to restart automatically. By using the following code you disable that.

```
RegistryKey ourKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
ourKey = ourKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
ourKey.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 0);
// Kill the explorer by the way you've post and do your other work
ourKey.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've seen this post before, but it doesn't seem like a very good idea to change a system-wide setting just for a one-shot action. What if a crash occurs after you set the value to 0 and before you set it back to 1?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque well my home Win has that option disabled (set to 0) that's why I've asked you about the Windows version (I thought it was version specific). So I think nothing problematic will happen yet you can test it yourself - googling around didn't show any strange behaviour. NVidia driver installer kills the explorer when installing new drivers, so if they do it (and they probably do it roughly the same way) I doubt anything really dangerous might happen. Yet it's up to you and your requirements.

Comment: Old, very old, but wouldn't it be better to save the current value of the registry key and restore it to that value when you're done ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using Process.Kill, try this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe", @"/F /IM explorer.exe");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The OP said: "Sure, I could call taskkill from my code, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution"